# Nav menu will not align to center

Tags: css, menu

I'm having problems getting a menu center aligned.

Tried settings nav and wrap-nav class to

```
margin 0 auto; width: 100%;
```

but still cannot get it working, so have reverted that back for my example linked below.

I've created a jsfiddle page to show me menu as it is now.
As you can see it sits over to the left, I would like to get this centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/x6vLep9g/

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: showing your HTML will help others view and solve quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  managed to center using the following:

```
.menu ul {
    display:inline-block;
}

.menucentre {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6vLep9g/5/)**

Did 2 things:

1) Added "text-align: center;" to ".menu ul"

```
.menu ul {list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0; text-align: center; }
```

2) Removed float from ".menu  ul li" & added display inline block.

```
.menu  ul li {position: relative; display:inline-block; background-color: #333;padding: 6px 5px 0px 5px; margin: 17px;}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, both these solutions are great for me. Sorry I can't tick both as a fix but only allows one. Thanks again for your help both

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6vLep9g/9/)Center it like this
change nav style to:
`nav {margin:15px 0px;text-align: center;}`

and also add `display:inline-block` to `.menu ul`
`.menu ul {list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;display:inline-block}`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6vLep9g/9/)